# Spotify Web API call throws 502 Bad Gateway Error

Tags: spotify, gateway

I am building a web application using the Spotify Web API. The calls are pretty straight forward and I don't understand if it is me doing something wrong, or if there is something wrong with the Spotify service.

I implemented the lookup call (works fine) and then add track IDs to my database when a button is clicked next to one of the results. I then do an ajax call to display that track in the "Play Button" iframe. 
Instead of showing my playlist now, I very often get a 502 Bad Gateway error. (This error also appears on the Spotify website where the example is supposed to be shown.)

Is this something I cause? My browser / system causes?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: This happens to me sporadically, too. Usually if I retry a given query after I get a 502 it works. So for the moment I've put retry loops around my query. But this is still frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

> (This error also appears on the Spotify website where the example is supposed to be shown.)

This suggests that the problem is on Spotify's side, assuming you're giving the Play Button a valid Spotify URI. Hang tight for a while and it should sort itself out.